# сложный запрос PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

не могу понять в чем ошибка, в то время как количество параметров верное, и написаны они верно!
запрос:

```
$prepare = $this->dbPDO->prepare('SELECT category.id, category.parent_id, category_description.title FROM tori_category, tori_category_description  WHERE `tori_category_description.category_id` = :tori_category_description.category_id AND `tori_category_description.lang_id` = :tori_category_description.lang_id  ORDER BY `title` DESC ');
```

данные

```
$prepare->execute(Array
(
[tori_category_description.category_id] => tori_category.id
[tori_category_description.lang_id] => 1
))
```

выдает ошибку Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined' in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Именованный параметр `PDO` может использовать только символы `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, точка недопустима и парсер воспринимает не тот результат, на который вы рассчитываете. В мануале это похоже не описано, но [вот оно в исходнике](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.2/ext/pdo/pdo_sql_parser.re#L49).

Парсер считает, что ваш `:tori_category_description.category_id` - это параметр `:tori_category_description`, а следом без разделителя кусок запроса `.category_id`. Для `mysql` это недопустимо синтаксически, но это не ответственность парсера `pdo`, потому что например для postgresql это может быть нормальным оператором, выполняющим какую-то логику между переданным параметром `:tori_category_description` и полем `category_id` с помощью определённого для них оператора `.`.

Но параметр `:tori_category_description` вы не биндите, поэтому `PDO` жалуется на несоответствие параметров в запросе и в `execute`.

Comment: а как можно этот эже запрос переделать для pdo?

Comment: Заменить имена параметров на что угодно другое из букв, цифр и символа подчёркивания. Хоть `:category` и `:lang`

Comment: не совсем понял, голова уже параллелепипедная, можно пример?

Comment: @vkt 
`$prepare->execute(Array
(
[tori_category_description_category_id] => tori_category.id
[tori_category_description_lang_id] => 1
))`

Comment: @vkt и соответственно в запросе "SELECT" тоже изменить `:tori_category_description.category_id` на `tori_category_description_category_id`, так же и для `tori_category_description.lang_id`

Comment: @vkt проще говоря убрать точку из параметров

Answer (score 0):

Вы забыли к ключам массива добавить ":" т.е. массив переданный в execute должен быть таким

```
Array
(
':tori_category_description_category_id' => tori_category.id
':tori_category_description_lang_id' => 1
)
```

Comment: я уже пробовал но ничего не изменилось, квадратные скобки играют роль? (потому что они появились при выводе массива через print_r)

Comment: @vkt А у вас "tori_category.id" - это что?

Comment: Двоеточие при биндинге параметров необязательно

Comment: @Мелкий хмм - не знал... Ну тогда у меня сомнения только в tori_category.id

Comment: @BigTows это таблица tori_category с полем id